# Login using custom android activity no sdk dialog/webview

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse

i surfed net a lot to find some clue but could not find one.

i don't want to display fbdialog/web view to login facebook. **instead i want username and password EditText controls and a button on an activity.** user should be authorised on this button click. fb SDK is using dialog and webview. in facebook.java class of SDK there is written in comments that we can use a custom activity but how i dont have an idea. plz help